Google OAuth Login Works Locally but Fails After Deployment to Vercel Without Backend
I am facing an issue with Google OAuth login in my React app when deployed to Vercel. Here's the scenario:
Deployment URLs:

Base URL: https://acjessential.vercel.app/
Latest Deployment URL: https://acjessential-fs25ju3az-paulo-oliveiras-projects-d0079d90.vercel.app/

Behavior:

Local:

After logging in, I am redirected to the calendar page as expected. Both localStorage and sessionStorage contain the googleAccessToken.


Base URL (Vercel):

The Google sign-in animation appears, but I am redirected back to see the login button instead of the calendar.
Console shows user: null, and storage is empty.


Latest Deployment URL:

Shows error: "Access blocked: This app’s request is invalid."



My Configurations:

Google Cloud Project:

Authorized JavaScript Origins:

http://localhost:3000
https://acjessential.vercel.app


Authorized Redirect URIs:

http://localhost:3000
https://acjessential.vercel.app




Environment Variables in Vercel:

REACT_APP_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID
REACT_APP_GOOGLE_CALENDAR_API
REACT_APP_GOOGLE_CALENDAR_ID
REACT_APP_GOOGLE_API_SCOPES



What I've Tried:

Added latest deployment URL to authorized origins/redirects in Google Cloud.
Cleared browser cache, used incognito mode, and redeployed multiple times.

Current Problem:
On Vercel, after Google sign-in:

Redirect happens, but the login button is still displayed.
Console logs show user: null, and storage is empty.

Expected Behavior:
After login, the app should navigate to the calendar page and display it using the googleAccessToken.
Question:
Is there a configuration I might be missing in Google Cloud, Vercel, or my app code to make this work as expected on the deployed Vercel version?
